# How to determine the starting address of main

Tags: c, operating-system, stack, cpu-architecture

I am writing a stack tracing program which is similar to `backtrace` in gdb.

```
Example Program

void bar(int x, int y){
    trace(stdio);
}

void foo(){
    bar(1, 2);
}


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    foo();
}
```

It will print out

```
Function bar..
Function foo..
```

The problem is I have no idea how to stop when I reach main. I have a table that store the starting address of functions, include `main`.

My approach is for the `trace` function is, I will first read the `ebp` by writing a small assembly code. And hence I get the `return addr` for `trace` which is in `bar`.

So I can get the starting address of `trace` by adding an `offset`(determine by `CALL` instruction in `bar`) to the return address of `trace` (This make use of the relative IP)

But when I reach main, I can't use the same technique, the return address of `main` bring me to some memory area that I can't access.

How can I determine Im in `main` function already? (I hope to get the starting address of `main` )

Comment: What parts of `main()` are below its start address or past the address of the next function?

Comment: I want to get the address of start of `push %ebp` in `main`, what do you mean?

Comment: Ah, I read "I have a table..." as meaning you had the addresses beforehand, not that you're collecting them as you walk the stack - my mistake.

Comment: I'm being a bit naïve here... but what about `void *addr = (void*)main;`?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries available which solve this problem already, i.e., libunwind or the libc backtrace function: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

If you want to implement this yourself you could parse the ELF header of the executable. This way you can get the function names and start addresses / lengths. So you can check if you are already in a function called "main".